# Gelocation not working in Android - PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps, geolocation, phonegap-build

I am making an simple PhoneGap app which gets the users location.

the code used for my build is from examples of the maps [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

**Following is my xml code:**

```
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ee6e73" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />

<feature name="Geolocation">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

While the app works perfectly on the browser, the android version does not load the location.

Further noticed that maps.gstatic.com and mts.googleapis.com is not loading from the app, both are loaded in the browser which then results in providing the location

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

to avoid  confusions, I have used the default config.xml generated by phonegap desktop app, still the location is not obtained.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>new</name>
<description>
Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />

<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin to get lat long from android device and then call map on success of that plugins calls

[Cordova Plugin Geolocation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation)

Add lat long to the map received into success function

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);
function appReady(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}   

// onSuccess Callback
// This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
// current GPS coordinates

var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Try this and let me know if this is working for you or not.

Comment: Thanks, but the plugin is already included in my code <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />.

Comment: Have you added `cordova.js` into your `.html` file or if you are building an app via `PhoneGap Build Online` then add `phonegap.js` also try calling this function on `deviceready event listner`

Comment: have tried this also but no luck. I dont have a physical deivce, could it be an issue on the emulator?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30004399/3840093) is a fix for some emulator to work geolocation plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but neither does that help

Comment: So, have you tried this into real device ? Just once try it in real device and if it is not working then have to check either your other app code or android manifest file

Comment: i don't have one unfortunately :( I dont think i can share the apk here. I am using the phonegap build, hence the manifest file is obfuscated. I dont have anything in the code apart from whats in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my build to

```
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
```

you have to Remove

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm" />
```

and

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

from your code and add  the below code

for android

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"  spec="0.3.12" source="npm"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information"  spec="0.2.15" source="npm" />
```

for IOS

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"  spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git"/>
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information"  spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git" />
```

and use this to load the location

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(zoomToLocation, locationError, { maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 7500 });

 function zoomToLocation(position) {
            var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

Comment: thanks, but no change in the outcome it still does not get the geolocation

Comment: @meetrk85 : I am loading the location from Navigator